# What would p(a,b|a) be equal to?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

What is p(a,b|a) equal to in conditional probability? Any sort of breakdown as to why it might be equal to p(b|a) would be helpful (if it is true in all cases).

My reasoning for asking this question came from a Hastie's (2001) book where one is trying to find E(f(a,b)|a) in the partial dependence plots section. It then got me curious about p(a,b|a).

Comment: Try by writing the definition of conditional probability: P(A, B | A) = P(A, A, B) / P(A) = P(A, B) / P(A) = P(B | A).

Answer (score 1):

If $a$, $b$ are some events, e.g. $a$: it is raining, $b$: you have your umbrella with you, then, you are asking for *P(it is raining and you have umbrella | it is raining)*. You know that it is raining, so, intuitively, no need to question if it is raining or not again, and this probability equals to *P(you have umbrella | it is raining)*, which will mean $p(a,b|a)=p(b|a)$.

In case of random variables, as @Robin points out, if $A$ and $B$ are the RVs responsible for $a$ and $b$ respectively, the expression should be written in this form: $P(A=a, B=b|A=a)$ in order to prevent any confusions. Because, if $a$ and $b$ are just constants, then what you are asking seems like $p(1,2|1)$, which is ambiguous.

If $a$ and $b$ are random variables themselves, then we lack the particular values. The expression should be like $P(a=a',b=b'|a=a'')$. Here, if $a'' \neq a'$, then given that $a$ equals to $a''$, it cannot be equal to $a'$, and the probability will be $0$. If, $a''=a'$, then again, since we know what the value of $a$ is, the probability will be equal to $p(b=b'|a=a')$, which can be summarized with the help of a $\delta$ function if you like to write it in a compact form, as in @Robin's answer. (P.S. Don't confuse $\delta$ with continuous dirac-delta function).

Comment: This is a fantastic response (so is Robin's). Question, are you using the dirac-delta function just to formally extend that you have checked the 0-probability possibilities when a' != a''. Hence, the only non-zero probability (being 1 since it's one option), is when a' = a''. In a way, you had to apply the "cartesian" product of all a' and a'', so to say, to give it a proper analysis. But a compact form would be to say p(A=a,B=b|A=a) results in p(B=b|A=a) for all non-zero probabilities?

Comment: Yes, you understand the $\delta$ function usage, though it is not "dirac-delta". It is more like Indicator function, which gives 1 when inside expression is correct. And, yes p(A=a,B=b|A=a)  = p(B=b|A=a)

Answer (score 0):

You have $P(A = a', B = b \mid A = a) = P(B = b \mid A = a) \delta(a = a')$ where $\delta(a = a')$ is equal to 1 only if $a = a'$

Comment: Would it instead be equal to p(A,B|A) = p(A|B,A)*p(B|A)? Where I'm getting stuck on is the p(A|B,A) = p(A,B,A)/(p(A,B), which I assume should equal to 1, right? So, what were' left at the end is p(B|A) = p(A,B|A).

Comment: Is this some rule of probability

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes. It is the bayesian decompositions, if you will, of conditional probabilities.